# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to show users that their level is both `admin` and `operator`.

```
 @foreach(\App\User::whereLevel('admin')->get() || \App\User::whereLevel('operator')->get() as $user)
```

But I get this error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\new\shopping\resources\views\Admin\levelAdmin\create.blade.php)

Comment: Don't do queries in a view... That is what a Controller is for. Perform the query there, confirm results, and pass to the view. Also, it will be much easier to debug why the result of your query is not iterable in a Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using `(\App\User::whereLevel('admin')->get() || \App\User::whereLevel('operator')->get()` cause one of the queries can be empty or if you want to fetch users where `level` matches `admin` OR `operator`.

For the first case, try somenthing like this:

```php
@if(!empty(\App\User::whereLevel('admin')->get()))
    @foreach(\App\User::whereLevel('admin')->get() as $user)
        //
    @endforeach
@else
    @foreach(\App\User::whereLevel('operator')->get()  as $user)
        //
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If you want to get Users where `level` matches `operator` or `admin`, you shoul modify your query with somenthin like this:

```php
@foreach(\App\User::where('level', 'admin')->orWhere('level', 'operator')->get() as $user)
    //
@endforeach
```

Comment: Happy to help you.